# "As this holds for all values of $x$, then something is true" logic.

Tags: logic

Often times there is an argument used that is mathematically unclear to me. We typically have a relation such as: $ax = bx$. Then the logic is typically, "since this expression holds true for all $x$, then $a = b$.

Can someone explain this logic to me? Can someone provide a contradiction where the expression only holds true for a finite number of values of $x$ and hence $a \neq b$? Is there a name given to this type of logic? It seems slightly handwavy to me at this point.

Thank you.

Comment: What if $x=0$?  Once $ax=bx$ for some $x$ invertible, we have $a=b$, so the only case in which this can't happen is when $x=0$.

Comment: Well, it holding for any non-zero $x$ suffices - there's really no more general logical principle behind this. It's just division.

Comment: Okay, let's generalize so you see my point. Consider the expression: $ax + by = cx + dy$. The argument now is: since this expression holds true for all $x$ and all $y$, then $a=c$ and $b=d$. This is not obtainable by simple division. It is a line of reasoning that I do not understand.

Comment: @Johnver Sure it is. Consider the cases $(x,y)=(1,0)$ and $(x,y)=(0,1)$ - if it holds for all pairs, it holds for those pairs - that gives you those equations. (And, more generally, I suspect that any pair of points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ at which the equation holds which are not multiples of each other, would allow you to reach the same conclusion algebraically)

Comment: When you write $ax=bx$ without any qualifiers, wouldn't the appropriate interpretation be that $a,b,x$ are specific values and the equation is just a *single* equation? Or, perhaps alternatively, that $a$ and $b$ are values, and that $x$ is an unknown that you must solve for? In any case, if you *start* with the assumption that a relation holds true for all $x$, then you have to actually **say** it holds true for all $x$! You can't omit that part. As far as I can tell, you've given exactly zero true examples of the logic you're talking about, so I don't understand your question to be honest.

Comment: Now, if you *truly do* start with the "for all" qualifier, then you can proceed. For instance, let's assume $ax+by=cx+dy$ holds true for all values of $x$ and $y$. (Notice that I explicitly say it holds true for all $x$ and $y$; I don't obligate the reader to read my mind or navigate ambiguous interpretations.) Here $a,b,c,d$ are some numbers that we will make deductions about. If it's true for all $x$ and $y$, then *in particular* it must be true when $x=1$ and $y=0$ (i.e. $a=c$), and it must *in particular* be true when $x=0$ and $y=1$ (i.e. $b=d$). Right?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to look at it as $f(x) = ax, g(x) = bx$. Then what you're saying is that $(\forall x \in X)(f(x) = g(x))$. This means that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every value, which sounds pretty much like saying $f$ and $g$ are the same function.

Answer (score 0):

So, this really depends on what you are talking about.  What system are we dealing with?  What set and what operations?
In a field (such as the real or complex numbers), this holds true by the definition as all values (all x) have a multiplicative inverse. i.e. there exists some value y s.t. xy = 1 (where 1 is the multiplicative identity).
However there are other systems this is not true in.  For example this will not hold true for all rings.

Basically until we know what system you are working in, it is impossible to say whether or not the this statement is logically sound.

Comment: This is true in any ring with uniity: if $ax = bx$ is true for all $x$, then in particular it is true for $x = 1$.

Comment: @fkraiem Fair enough, but not all rings have unity (at least with the textbooks I used).  That said, I know that some texts assume all rings have unity.

Answer (score 0):

In logic terminology, this is an inference rule called [universal generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

From Velleman's [How to Prove it](https://books.google.com/books/about/How_to_Prove_It.html?id=sXt-ROLLNHcC)  (2006):

> **To prove a goal of the form $∀x P(x)$:**
>
> Let $x$ stand for an arbitrary object and prove $P(x)$. The letter $x$ must be a new variable in the proof. If $x$ is already being used in the proof to stand for something, then you must choose an unused variable, say $y$, to stand for the arbitrary object, and prove $P(y)$.

That is, if you can show that an arbitrary $x \in D$ has some property $P$, then you can conclude that this holds for all $x \in D$. Now why should this hold? Because you didn't assume anything of $x$, except that $x \in D$. Then if you successfully show that $P(x)$ is the case, it will be the case as well for all other elements of the domain, i.e. $\forall x \in D, P(x)$.

This arbitrariness of $x$ is assured by the constraint that $x$ must be a new variable, that is, it must be not free in any of the hypothesis of your derivation.